# postgresql migrating JSON to JSONB

Tags: postgresql, ddl, jsonb

In postgresql 9.4 the new JSONB was incorporated.

On a live DB in postgresql 9.3 I have a JSON column.

I want to migrate it to JSONB.

Assuming I migrated the DB first to 9.4 (using pg_upgrade). What do I do next?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_with_json
  ALTER COLUMN my_json
  SET DATA TYPE jsonb
  USING my_json::jsonb;
```

Comment: Are there any benchmarks on how fast this is? Ideally with how that scales with the number of records.

Comment: Asked this as [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042429/roughly-how-fast-is-json-jsonb-column-conversion-in-postgres-9-4).

Comment: In Rails console:
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE table_with_json ALTER COLUMN my_json SET DATA TYPE jsonb USING my_json::jsonb')`

Comment: This doesn't work when migrating in postgresql 9.5

Comment: If anyone using old sqlalchemy-utils and is wondering about JSONB not as sqlalchemy-util data type, you can use from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB in your model. and migrate DB as above answer

Answer (score 38):

In the context of Rails, here is an ActiveRecord migration alternative:

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { change_column :models, :attribute, 'jsonb USING CAST(attribute AS jsonb)' }
    dir.down { change_column :models, :attribute, 'json USING CAST(attribute AS json)' }
  end
end
```

I don't know how this compares to the accepted answer performance-wise, but I tested this on a table with 120 000 records, each record having four `json` columns and it took me about a minute to migrate that table. Of course, I guess it depends on how complex the `json` structure is.

Also, notice that if your existing records have a default value of `{}`, you have to add to the above statements `default: {}`, because otherwise you'll have `jsonb` columns, but the default value will remain as `'{}'::json`.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you use `reversible do ... end` rather than `def up ... end` and `def down ... end`?

Comment: @OzBarry because of convention and because using `change` in combination with `reversible` is the "recommended" way. Have a look at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method, in particular 3.8 Using the change Method, 3.9 Using reversible, 3.10 Using the up/down Methods

Comment: Could you add this answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024841/how-do-i-migrate-an-activerecord-model-attribute-from-json-to-jsonb . That way it will be the exact right answer as this question didn't actually mention rails