# How do I migrate an ActiveRecord model attribute from json to jsonb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, jsonb, rails-postgresql

What should the migration look like? I would like to take advantage of the jsonb array querying technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write the migration this way:

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { change_column :models, :attribute, 'jsonb USING CAST(attribute AS jsonb)' }
    dir.down { change_column :models, :attribute, 'json USING CAST(attribute AS json)' }
  end
end
```

I don't know how this compares performance-wise to other solutions, but I tested this on a table with 120,000 records, each record having four `json` columns and it took me about a minute to migrate that table. Of course, I guess it depends on how complex the `json` structure is.

Also, notice that if your existing records have a default value of `{}`, you have to add to the above statements `default: {}`, because otherwise you'll have `jsonb` columns, but the default value will remain as `'{}'::json`.

Comment: This fails with rails `5.2.4.3`. Caused by:
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 1: SELECT 'jsonb USING associations::jsonb'::regtype::oid
               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "jsonb USING associations::jsonb"

Comment: Worked for me in Rails 7.